# customize TabView design in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

I want to design a tab view looks like this **any example**??[image]

I know how to make a tab view [using this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

**Ans **[LINK](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below link . I think this is what you are looking for.

http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html

You can also look at this https://github.com/mta452/iTab

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But it says Page not found
Error: 404

Comment: This is working link.I don't get any error...

Comment: when you get this error?

Comment: when I try to get the code from Download: http://ul.to/1678n1

Comment: @bumba  chk my updated answer :)